# Conditionally display a CEWP depending on form content type?

Tags: content-type, list-form, content-editor-web-part

I have a request list with different content types set up for different types of request.  I would like to show a different CEWP at the top of each form depending on which type of request is being made.  I do not have access to SharePoint Designer.  Is there another way to create different .aspx pages for different content types?  OR can I conditionally show different CEWPs on the single newform.aspx?   Currently I link to the different content types NewForm.aspx by appending the content type ID to the URL.  Thanks

Comment: Why different CEWPs, and not the same CEWP that shows different content depending on the content type?

Comment: +1 for @Christophe... this make sense as it would be easier to control content in single CEWP than adding different CEWP for different content type..

Comment: Yes that would work.  I don't 'need' to have two separate CEWPs.  How can I show different content in the one CEWP, depending on content type?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Unless you create your own URL to NewForm.aspx without parameters,
the ContentTypeId is by default present as a QueryString parameter.

So you can add some JavaScript to that single NewForm.aspx (edit in advanced mode) 
just before the table of the form, that matches by ContentTypeId and prints a header.

If you don't have SharePoint Designer add a ContentEditorWebPart **above** the Form in the page.

```
<script>
    JSRequest.EnsureSetup();//proces all parameters from the URL Query String
    var ctID=JSRequest.QueryString['ContentTypeId'];//get the ContentTypeId from the URL
    var titles={
        '0x0100223....010019ABEA5C55C59D4383F98D5A938894D8' : 'Expense',
        '0x0100223....02006C9B8D0CCE23024EA3A01C9A93FAFBB3' : 'Invoice',
    };
    //get a defined Title or the CTId when it isn't defined
    var title = titles[ctID] || ctID;
    //directly write the Title in the document (so the CEWP must be at the top)
    document.write( String.format('<h1 title="{1}">New: {0}</h1>', title,ctID ));
</script>
```

#### Always get the correct ContentTypeId

**After** pageload the ContentType info is always present in:

```
WPQ2FormCtx.ItemContentTypeId
and
WPQ2FormCtx.ItemContentTypeName
```

But you better make sure you reference the correct WebPart (WPQ2 most of the time)

Comment: Thanks Danny.  I understand how to add code to a page using a CEWP webpart, but JavaScript is beyond my abilities.  Does that code cause a different heading to display for each content type?  ie if content type id = '0x0100223....010019ABEA5C55C59D4383F98D5A938894D8' , the form heading will be 'Expense'?

Comment: Yes. I added some comments. Use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to play with JavaScript snippets. Note that JSRequest is SharePoint specific code.

Comment: Hi again, I'm making progress, thanks, but could you show me how to stop an additional title being added after each time I create a new request?  After I have made a few requests, the following gets added to the bottom of the code: <h1 title="0x0100FBA03415B8BE3B4996DAB90AD509E44C">New: Domestic / Trans-Tasman</h1>
<h1 title="0x0100FBA03415B8BE3B4996DAB90AD509E44C">New: Domestic / Trans-Tasman</h1>
<h1 title="0x010069D1A9F47BFC3B49B9F65DEDD7EEBD2200D7C5BB9689E71340844DB3B320C02E8A">New: International</h1>

Comment: Yes ``document.write`` will always add a line. You have to learn more JavaScript to add a ``DIV`` element once and change the ``innerHTML`` of that ``DIV``